# поиск по файлам PHP (ускорить)

Tags: php, поиск

слишком медленный поиск данных в файлах, любая идея, как можно ускорить? 
в папке есть файлы, каждый файл имеет структуру:

```
url:man.report
<title> man.report - это наилучший источник информации по теме . </title>
<h1> man.report </h1>
 man.report это наилучший источник интересующей Вас информации. От общеизвестных тем, до того, что вы даже не ожидаете найти; на man.report есть все. Надеемся, что вы найдете то, что ищете.
|||
url:soft-trans.ru
<title> Софттранс | Программы для транспорта </title>
<h1> Софттранс </h1>
|||

и т.д.
```

размер файлов общий ~1ГБ, время поиска ~200сек., код поиска:

```
<?php declare (strict_types = 1);
error_reporting(-1);//выводить всё

$start = microtime(true);//запускаем таймер

function my_search($search, $text)
    {
        $q = 1;
        foreach($search as $v)
            {
                if(!mb_strstr($text, $v))
                    {   
                        $q = 0;
                        break;
                    }
            }
        return($q);
    }

$search = trim(mb_strtolower('ssd цена'));
$s = $search;

$search = explode(' ', $search);

foreach($search as &$v)
    {
        $v = ' '.$v.' ';
    }
unset($v);

$files = array_diff(scandir(__DIR__.'/file/'), array('..', '.'));

$u = [];
$c = 0;
foreach($files as $value)
    {
        $e = $value;
        //тут в цикле перебираю файлы
        $value = file_get_contents(__DIR__.'/file/'.$value);

        $value = mb_strtolower($value);

        $site_arr = explode(PHP_EOL.'|||'.PHP_EOL, $value);

        foreach($site_arr as $value1)
            {
                $value2 = str_replace([PHP_EOL,'.',',','-'], ' ', $value1);//,'-'

                $q = my_search($search, $value2);

                if($q)
                    {
                        ++$c;

                        $url_site = substr(strstr($value1, 'url:'), 4);//взял ссылку страницы
                        $url_site = strstr($url_site, PHP_EOL, TRUE);

                        $value1 = strip_tags($value1);

                        foreach($search as $v)
                            {
                                $value1 = str_replace(trim($v), '<b>'.$v.'</b>', $value1);
                            }
                        unset($v);

                        $u[] = '<a href="http://'.$url_site.'/" target="_blank">http://'.$url_site.'/'.'</a>'.' | '.$e.'<br />'.$value1.'<br />';
                    }

                if($c > 60)
                    {
                        break 2;
                    }
            }
        unset($value1);
    }
unset($value);

if(!empty($u))
    {
        $u = array_unique($u);//удаляю дубли

        $u = implode('<hr>', $u);
    } else
        {
            $u = 'ничего не найдено';
        }

echo $u.'<br />';
echo 'всего: '.$c.'<br />';

echo '<br />'.'Время работы скрипта:  ' . (microtime(true) - $start) . ' секунд<br /><br />';
?>
```

Comment: К примеру `system("grep -R 'search fraze'  .  ")`

Comment: я ищу слова, а не фразу

Comment: да без разницы.

Comment: как на счёт проиндексировать документы заранее? шустрый поиск обычно так и работает.

Comment: Naumov - у меня есть фраза для поиска, я разбиваю её на слова и в каждом элементе массива (на каждом "сайте") ищу все те слова, которые есть в искомой фразе (это видно по коду), в вашем варианте я смогу найти только фразу, поправьте если я ошибаюсь

Comment: Lexx918 - укажите в какую сторону копать пожалуйста, я не совсем понял, как можно проиндексировать файл

Comment: полнотекстовые индексы в СУБД, либо поисковые машины типа сфинкса

Comment: teran - не хватает ресурсов на бд, проект под свои нужды "на том что есть". Неужели код, что я привёл - самый оптимальный? Может есть вариант его оптимизировать?

Comment: @Василий, как СУБД можно использовать sqlite (https://www.sqlite.org/). Как поисковый движок PHP Lucene (https://github.com/pucene/pucene)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> укажите в какую сторону копать пожалуйста, я не совсем понял, как можно проиндексировать файл

Как вы уже умеете делать внутри цикла - открываете файл (кстати, посмотрите ещё на [glob](http://php.net/glob) для поиска файлов), подготавливаете его к поиску, затем ищите все слова в нём по которым может быть произведён поиск (например, регуляркой `\b\w{2,}\b`, или `explode` по пробелу, убрав перед этим все знаки препинания, спец.символы и переносы строк, или ещё как-то на ваш выбор).

Из найденных слов оставляете только уникальные. Получается массив уникальных полезных для поиска слов конкретного файла.

```
$wordsFromFileFoo = ["ssd", "быстрее", "hdd"];
$wordsFromFileBar = ["как", "настроить", "принтер"];
```

Создаёте ещё один огромный массив вообще всех слов всех файлов. Слова файла добавляете в этот массив (постепенно в нём накопятся все слова и добавлять как правило будет уже нечего так что он не будет супер огромный). Каждое слово в этом общем для всех массиве слов будет иметь свой индекс.

```
$wordsFromAllFiles = [
  "ssd",
  "быстрее",
  "hdd",
  "как",
  "настроить",
  "принтер",
];
```

Теперь тот массив, который содержит только слова конкретного файла, превратите в только набор индексов, которые соответствуют каждому слову и общего массива. Это позволит сократить их размер.

```
$wordsFromFileFoo = [0, 1, 2];
$wordsFromFileBar = [3, 4, 5];
```

Индекс готов! Сохраните все эти массивы в файлы - общий массив всех слов и массив индексов слов каждого файла (обязательно посмотрите на [SplFixedArray](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.splfixedarray.php)). Промежуточные массивы со словами каждого файла больше не нужны.

Как искать? Искомую фразу, как вы уже делали, делите на слова. Каждое слово ищите в общем массиве всех слов - получаете индекс каждого слова. В этом месте уже можно принять решение - нет слова в индексе - не будет и в файлах, и фразу можно не искать.

Если все слова есть в индексе - перебираете массивы индексов каждого файла и в них ищите через [in_array](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.in-array.php) или [array_search](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-search.php) эти самые индексы. Нашли все? - Файл содержит все искомые слова. Не все? - Файл частично содержит слова. Ни одного? - Файл не содержит слов.

К сожалению при изменении файлов (изменение старых, добавление новых, удаление) индекс придётся обновлять, перестраивать. На лету, только меняя часть затронутую файлом, или целиком, - тема отдельного вопроса. Главное - придётся.

Можно пойти дальше и навернуть, например, релевантности к поиску. Смотреть в каком порядке были слова в искомой фразе и в каком порядке они идут в индексе. И сколько слов между ними. Если мало и порядок тот же - вы ближе к нужному результату, чем если слова идут в другом порядке и их разделяет несколько других слов.

Ещё неплохо приводить все словоформы к инфинитивам. Так и словарь будет меньше и поиск ускорится. Либо оставить как есть для более высокой релевантности. С другой стороны без поиска по словоформам вы чаще будете промахиваться даже если фраза более менее отражает суть текста в файле, но не совпала немного по приставкам и окончаниям в словах.

Если фраза очень длинная, можно считать как много её слов в том или ином файле, и сортировать выборку по этому числу. Больше число - больше соответствие файла запросу.

Comment: Спасибо! Очень подробно, подумаю как реализовать

Comment: @Василий ну как?

Comment: на данный момент мне сделали на c# поиск и пока меня это устроило, 8 секунд против 180 на пхп, ваш вариант я рассмотрю чуть позже, пока возникла проблема схлопывания данных и решаю её

Answer (score 0):

От простого к сложному:

- Для каждой записи производится поиск с помощью `mb_strstr`. Поск `strpos` будет немного быстрее.
- В вашем примере некоторое время тратится на подготовку (разбиение по `|||`, удаление знаков препинания), её можно выполнить заранее.
- Вы можете построить индекс, где каждому слову будет соответствовать список документов, в которых это слово встречается. Тогда вы довольно быстро найдёте несколько списков, их пересечение будет результатом поиска. Однако обратите внимание, что вам будет необходимо перестраивать индекс при изменении (удалении, добавлении новых) документов.
- Можно распараллелить поиск.

Кроме этого можно применить некоторые уловки. Например использовать существующие инструменты для поиска. Погрепав (как советуют вам в комментариях) файлы, в которых встречаются нужные вам слова, можно сократить количество файлов для поиска. Можно использовать базу данных или поисковый движок.

Comment: 1. да, это наверное так, но по моим тестам mb_strpos медленнее на 5 секунд примерно. 2. разбивку нельзя заранее сделать т.к. поиск нужен именно в блоке между |||, удаление знаков есть/нет практически не влияет на скорость. 3. да, вот это можно попробовать. 4. какие варианты посоветуете?

Comment: @Василий например так https://habr.com/post/148688/